# Can't run scene using AssImp on OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, crash, nvidia, assimp

I'm using AssImp to parse a simple cube (as an example to test) to be used on OpenGl. But when OpenGl starts I see a glimpse of my scene with cube in it followed by this error on my Nvidia driver:

http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3007

OpenGl shuts down and this has been happening always after I started using AssImp.

My Nvidia is the GeForce 9300M GS.
The code that draws the cube is very simple:

```
    #include "Object.h"

Object::Object(string filename){

    scene = importer.ReadFile(filename,aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace|aiProcess_Triangulate|aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices|aiProcess_SortByPType);

    if(!scene){
        cout << importer.GetErrorString();
    }

}

void Object::draw(){

    if(!scene)
        return;

    if(!scene->mNumMeshes){
        cout << "NO PRIMITIVES" << endl;
        return;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < scene->mNumMeshes ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < scene->mMeshes[i]->mNumFaces ; j++)
        {
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

            glVertex3f(scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[0]].x,
                scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[0]].y,
                scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[0]].z);
            glVertex3f(scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[1]].x,
                scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[1]].y,
                scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[1]].z);
            glVertex3f(scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[2]].x,
                scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[2]].y,
                scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[j].mIndices[2]].z);

            glEnd;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever had this crash on the Nvidia driver using AssImp?

I have no idea what the problem may be. I've used OpenGl in this computer numerous times with more complex shapes building entire scenes but I never got this.

Comment: Have you used a debugger? On what line does it crash?

Comment: I have, I'm using Visual Studio and it doesn't say on what line is crashes, simple turns off the display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the double for loop, you probably want to write `glEnd();` instead of `glEnd;` (which is valid C++ but the compiler issues a warning about it)

Comment: Thanks! Since it didnt issue an error, I ended up not realizing it was wrong in the first place.